# How to write a tab.gz file using pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe and I want my output files to be in tab.gz extensions.

```
df.write\
        .option("delimiter", "\t")\
        .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")\
        .save(
            s3_directory,
            format='csv',
            header=True,
            emptyValue='',
            compression="gzip"
    )
```

this creates the output files as

**part-xyz.csv.gz**

how can I change the config to make it save as  **part-xyz.tab.gz** please?

Comment: did you mean tar.gz, not tab.gz?

Comment: @mck: The requirement I have clearly specified tab.gz. So I guess I need tab.gz

Answer (score -1):

As much as "tab.gz" looks like a typo, have you tried to specify "path" argument:

```
file_path = s3_directory + "part-xyz.tab.gz"
df.write\
    .option("delimiter", "\t")\
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")\
    .save(
        path=file_path,
        format='csv',
        header=True,
        emptyValue='',
        compression="gzip"
)
```